# How to show recent searches in UIlabel from Google Places Autocomplete for swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Is there a way to save my recent searches on Google Place Autocomplete iOS controls?

Comment: What did you mean?

Comment: like when i was location data from google place autocomplete , then this location data show my uilabel in my viewcontroller.